# Draw radius border to imageview or textview in one corner in Android

Tags: android, css

I need to draw a border to an imageview or a textview in my app, but I need to draw it only in one corner, like the image.

[image]

I do a shape but i get border in all 4 sides:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#FF000000" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>  
    <padding android:left="1px" android:top="1px"
        android:right="0px" android:bottom="0px" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="8px" /> 
</shape>
```

How can I to do make it like in the image?

Thanks, Mattia

Answer (score 6):

Use this code will solve it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
   <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" /> 
     <corners android:topLeftRadius="15dp" /> 
    </shape>
 </item>
<item android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp">
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="#000000" /> 
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="15dp" /> 
  </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

you have to make adjustment in the ( layout Xml ) also as:

android:layout_width

android:layout_height

android:paddingTop

android:paddingLeft

this is the output :

[image]

hope this help.

Comment: No for me it doesen't work, here is what i see: http://mattialori.net/imageview.png

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved. Using `inset` drawable we can achieve this easily and more customization we can do with less code. Use this `twoside_border.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- inset: It can remove border from any other side-->
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:insetBottom="-15dp"
android:insetRight="-15dp">

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="20dp"
        android:color="#ED302F" />

     <!--<corners
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
       />-->

    <!--<solid android:color="#f50a0a" />-->
</shape>
```

`insetBottom` & `insetRight` **-dp** values helps to hide the border where we do not need and as a output :

[two side border image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a3T1.png)

to get corner curve remove the commented line in the above code

```
<corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp"/>
```

now we can see the curve bend

[border with curve image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxbm1.png)

Use this `xml` in `frame layout` like below how I did & adjust the padding or margin according to your need, so that it fit inside the border image which look like a frame.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/your_image_file" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/twoside_border" />

        </FrameLayout>
```