# Android Button Trimmed Corner using Style

Tags: android, styles

I want the button to look like trimed from one corner.

I can add gradient to different states, using the following, but how to trim the corner like this ?

```
<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/endColor"
            android:startColor="@color/startColor"
            android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside shape, theirs one more attribute called **corners** use that and you will be able to get the desired effect. :)

```
 <corners android:radius="5dp" />
```

Tutorial [here.](http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-layout-rounded-corner-border/)

For one [corner.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495265/draw-radius-border-to-imageview-or-textview-in-one-corner-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
<shape android:shape="<replace with shape>" >

    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/endColor"
        android:startColor="@color/startColor"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"            
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: corner will give the round shape to button, but i like the button to look like similar to, when you fold corner of paper.

Comment: I don't think that's possible here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) but you can always make a 9.patch drawable with the shape and make it work.

Comment: Or do I have to use image button ?

Comment: Yes, i think you need to use a imageButton